# How can I get the current script name of a script running in parent script's shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How can I get the name of a child script that is running in the shell of it's parent?

consider script1.sh;

```
#this is script 1
echo "$0"
. ./script2.sh
```

and script2.sh;

```
#this is script 2
echo "$0"
```

Since script2.sh is being executed in **[sourced from]** the same shell as script1.sh, the output of running these scripts are both;

```
./script1.sh
```

How can get the name of script2.sh within script2.sh?

Comment: Don't use the `.sh` suffix on your script: https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are **sourcing** a script, not running it. Therefore, you are looking for `BASH_SOURCE`.

```
$ cat test.sh 
echo $BASH_SOURCE

$ . ./test.sh 
./test.sh
```

**Update:**

Some people posted that `BASH_SOURCE` is indeed an array and, while this is actually true, I don't think you need to use all the syntax boilerplate because. `"$BASH_SOURCE"` (yes, you should quote your variables) will return the first element of the array, exactly what you are looking for.

Said that, it would be useful to post and example of using `BASH_SOURCE` as an array so here it goes:

```
$ cat parent.sh 
#!/bin/bash

. ./child.sh

$ cat child.sh 
#!/bin/bash

. ./grandchild.sh

$ cat grandchild.sh 
#/bin/bash

echo "BASH_SOURCE: $BASH_SOURCE"
echo "child      : ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
echo "parent1    : ${BASH_SOURCE[1]}"
echo "parent2    : ${BASH_SOURCE[2]}"

$ ./parent.sh 
BASH_SOURCE: ./grandchild.sh
child      : ./grandchild.sh
parent1    : ./child.sh
parent2    : ./parent.sh
```

Comment: Don't forget to quote your variables! Also, since `BASH_SOURCE` is an array, it's clearer to explicitly get the first element. So, `echo "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"`

Comment: `BASH_SOURCE` is an array. In the OP scenario, `BASH_SOURCE[0]` is script2 and  `BASH_SOURCE[1]` is script1.

Comment: @ichramm @ wjandrea @glennjackman Thank all three of you for your insight! I just figured I'd add something for anybody viewing this in the future. `BASH_SOURCE` is **reversed-indexed(?)**, meaning that `BASH_SOURCE[0]` always refers to the explicit script it's referenced in. `BASH_SOURCE[1]` refers to the parent script and so on. This is a good thing and exacty what I needed.

Comment: @glennjackman @wjandrea `BASH_SOURCE`  can behave an array on an scalar depending on how you use it. `$BASH_SOURCE` (without brace expansion) will return only the first element of the array.

Comment: And did you know that scalars can give you their zero'th element? `echo ${HOME[0]}`